# How to auto calculate whenever the user inputs a digit in textfield

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a JTextField to be auto updated everytime the users types a value (without pressing Enter key) into another JTextField.
In instance for what I want my program to be is google currency converter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field.

An event will be generated whenever text is added or removed from the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and a working example.